# Evaluation of Fresnel coefficient for $\theta_{i}>\theta_{cr}$

Tags: optics

For a TE wave the Fresnel coefficient $r$ is:
$$r=\frac{\cos(\theta_{i})-\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2(\theta_{i})}}{\cos(\theta_{i})+\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2(\theta_{i})}}$$
if $\theta_{i}>\theta_{cr} \rightarrow (n^2-\sin^2(\theta_{i}))<0 \rightarrow $
$$\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2(\theta_{i})}=\pm i\sqrt{-n^2+\sin^2(\theta_{i})}$$
So I have for $r$ four possibilities, according to the signs you put. You can verify that two possibilities give the real number 1, while the two other give two complex conjugate number with module=1. I mean $r=[1;e^{ia};e^{-ia}]$. So in all the cases the coefficient $R=|r^2|$ is 1 but, the reflected wave can have 3 different phases, which doesn't make sense. Someone knows where I am wrong?